# Add a different view in between RecyclerView items without using viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After doing a pretty long research on SO and other sites and reaching deadends, I am posting a new question. Here goes:

I have implemented a RecyclerView that uses **only 1 list item type** (i don't need to use multiple layout items in the recycler view based on position). The layout as shown below: ***box 1 in image***

what i want to do is, based on some event(click or a push notification), add a different view between two items of the RecyclerView (basically anywhere within the RecyclerView list). The view as shown below. ***box 2 in image***

The following picture depicts what I want to achieve.
[the image with the list item type and view to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuA4k.png)

The contents of the view to be added comes from a different source that the data source passed to the RecyclerViewAdapter. so `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `adapter.notifyItemInserted()` should not be called (in my opinion).

Is there any way I can get the above mentioned result?

Comment: just a normal case where you have two item types. why dont you want to override `RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)`?

Comment: I dont need to deal with the position of the Recyclerview items. I just want to add a view irrespective of the rv items.

Comment: you have two different types of items (**box 1** and **box 2**) so just override `getItemViewType`, this method is for that exact purpose

Comment: @pskink using getItemViewType will inflate the layout in box 2. Box 2 doesn't necessarily need to be inflated. I want to add that view ,for example, when an action button on the toolbar is clicked.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @pskink can you tell me how you would add the view in box2 on click of a button instead??

Comment: just google for `recyclerview getItemViewType` like his: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView or this: http://code2concept.blogspot.com/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html